# "to risk being..." or "risk being..."

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, infinitives, bare-infinitive, being

I have two sentences:

Correct:

> The company was issued a warning and ordered to stop polluting or *risk* being shut down.

Incorrect:

> The company was issued a warning and ordered to stop polluting or *to risk* being shut down.

I've repeated the two sentences a dozen times and I'm pretty convinced that the second is not grammatically correct. I am trying to find the appropriate rule to explain to my EFL students WHY but being a native speaker, I can't figure it out.

I have tried searching for details about how to use the verb "to risk" but have only found explanations on whether the verb that follows should be a gerund or an infinitve. I thought maybe it was an imperative but it doesn't seem like it. Is it something to do with the passive form of *to be* + verb?

Comment: Would anyone **order a company to risk being** shut down? No need for the extra *to* there. You need to do X or you risk Y.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is an "order", I like to think of the contents of the order/picking between two choices as an imperative:

> (You there!) stop polluting or risk being shut down

So in an imperative sentence, you only use the base form of the verb.